# Should the OP post their opinion in the question?

Tags: discussion, meta

When posting a discussion on Meta, should I include my opinion in it?
Suppose I'd like to know the community's opinion on a given subject.

- Should I include my own opinion in the question or as an answer?
- Should I include it at all?
- What would be the perks of each approach?

---

**Note**: This is not about questions on the main SO, just the meta part.

*Inception: Should I include my opinion here? xD*

<sub>I can't find meta about this because everything about 'opinion' seems to be related to SO's opinion-based questions..</sub>

Comment: This is too vaguely worded to give much feedback on. Can you please be a little more specific? What is the opinion *about*?

Comment: I don't really know how to.. This is a general question. When someone comes to meta trying to know what the community thinks about something, should the OP include their own opinion about it? If so, where? (question or answer) @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters Example: I'd like to know what the community thinks about deleting a question automatically when it reaches -10 score. Should I include my opinion on this?

Comment: See, there is no indication of context here. Why not include that sentence in your question? "When I post a discussion topic on Meta, should I include my own opinion on the topic?" would already be a lot clearer.

Comment: Ah, so are you asking about *feature requests* now? That's a different beast again. Please [edit] your question to be clearer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's an **example** for a question asking for opinions, I'm not really requesting that. I'll edit the question

Comment: Yes, I understood it was an example. But take into account that right now this question is both unclear and too broad; narrowing it down to specifics (like feature-requests vs discussion posts vs support questions) would go a long way towards making it specific and clear.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that was just a bad example. If I have a feature request, my opinion would be in the question defending the feature. I just goofed there hehe

Comment: Well, if you state your opinion in the question, we can vote based on that.

Comment: Post your opinion if it makes the question make (more) sense. There isn't really a strict rule about when you should or shouldn't post your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your opinion to be discussed than post it as part of the question. If you have opinion on topic post as answer (question still need solid reason inline why subject is actually important).

Notes If you have no opinion it is probably too early to post the question.